# Ignore blank values in WPF chart control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

> I am working on WPF application which includes WPF chart. I am facing a situation.
> I want to draw the chart only for values by ignoring blank values.
> In application the data is contained by a datagrid and same data will be reflected in the graph, but datagrid having blank values(DBNull.Value).
> So, I want to generate graph with only values by ignoring the blank values.

Here is my code for generating graph.

```
for (int col = 1; col < dtGeneric.Columns.Count; col++)
{
    valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();
    gLineSeries= new System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.LineSeries();
    for (int row = 0; row < dtGeneric.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(XaxisValue))
        {
            XaxisValue = "0";
        }
        YAxisValue = dtGeneric.Rows[row][col].ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(YAxisValue))
        {
            YAxisValue = "0";
        }
        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>(XaxisValue, Convert.ToDouble(YAxisValue)));
   }

    gLineSeries.DependentValuePath = "Value";
    gLineSeries.Style = gLineSeries.PolylineStyle;
    gLineSeries.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
    gLineSeries.ItemsSource = valueList;
    gLineSeries.Title = dtGeneric.Columns[col].Caption.Replace('_', '.').ToString();
    gLineSeries.AnimationSequence = AnimationSequence.FirstToLast;
    chartControl.Series.Add(gLineSeries);
}
```

}

> As you can see in the code, I have used keyvaluepair to draw the graph. So I am unable to add null value in the Value of keyvaluepair. I have tried with double.NaN but that is not working.
>
> I have iterated all the columns because all the column will have its separate graph.
>
> I have tried one logic to create the graph which is:

```
for (int col = 1; col < dtGeneric.Columns.Count; col++)
{
    valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();
    gPositionLineSeries = new System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.LineSeries();
    for (int row = 0; row < dtGeneric.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtGeneric.Rows[row][0].ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtGeneric.Rows[row][col].ToString()))  //Null values will be ignored for graph generation...
        {
        XaxisValue = dtGeneric.Rows[row][0].ToString();
        YAxisValue = dtGeneric.Rows[row][col].ToString();
        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>(XaxisValue, Convert.ToDouble(YAxisValue)));
        }
        else
        {
           continue;
        }
    }
}
```

> Above code is working fine but the X-axis values in the graph is not in order.

Please tell me some solution.

Comment: In above both codes: XaxisValue = dtGeneric.Rows[row][0].ToString();  **0 is used because zero column is used for X axis values**

Comment: Can anybody help for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

use below code in if block

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[clm.Index].Value.ToString())
```